# How location simulation works under the hood in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, location, gpx

I've been experimenting with location simulation in Xcode. Turns out, when you build a debug app with the simulation turned on, it somehow hijacks Core Location feed for every app and you won't be able to get your real location until you build the debug app with this feature turned off.

How exactly does it work under the hood? Could it be LLDB injecting some code to Core Location library? 
Is there a way to do the same without Xcode?